# Writing large unknown size array in Cuda?

Tags: cuda

I have a process which I send data to Cuda to process and it outputs data that matches a certain criteria. The problem is I often don't know the size out of outputted array. What can I do?

I send in several hundred lines of data and have it processed in over 20K different ways on Cuda.  If the results match some rules I have then I want to save the results.  The problem is I cannot create a linked list in Cuda(let me know if I can) and memory on my card is small so I was thinking of using zero copy to have Cuda write directly to the hosts memory.  This solves my memory size issue but still doesn't give me a way to deal with unknown.

My intial idea was to figure out the max possible results and malloc a array of that size. The problem is it would be huge and most would not be used(800 lines of data * 20K possible outcomes = 16 Million items in a array..which is not likely).

Is there a better way to deal with variable size arrays in Cuda? I'm new to programming so ideally it would be something not too complex(although if it is I'm willing to learn it).

Comment: You can create a linked list in CUDA -- pointers are pointers, just like on the CPU.  But I wouldn't necessarily recommend doing so -- pointer chasing across parallel threads typically leads to incoherent memory accesses, which can be expensive.

Comment: How big are the results?  If they are just, say 4 bytes each (int or float), then 16 million items is not much -- it's only 64 MB. In that case allocating the max would probably be your best bet -- you can copy the results to a smaller buffer after you have them, and reuse the 64MB allocation.  If the results are, say 40 or 400 bytes each, though, then you might consider other approaches.

Comment: @harrism they are very small,  its just the video card I'm testing it on has very small memory and I trying to figure out if there was a efficient way to have the list grow on demand. Can I copy to another buffer while the cuda kernal is still running or would it have to be done?

Comment: There are lots of approaches, but they will all cost performance -- it may just be the price you pay.  One approach would be to let memory size be your limiter, and run your computation in smaller batches.  Another might be to use device-side malloc, which may not be as bad as you think -- Try it before you give up on it.  I think as in all things, getting something working before optimizing it is the best way to make good progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heap memory allocation using `malloc` in kernel code is expensive operation (it forces CUDA driver initialize kernel with custom heap size and manage memory operations inside the kernel).

Generally, CUDA device memory allocation is the main bottleneck of program performance. The common practice is to allocate all needed memory at the beginning and reuse it as long as possible.

I think that you can create such buffer that is big enough and use it instead of memory allocations. In worst case you can wrap it to implement memory allocation from this buffer. In simple simple case you can keep last free cell in your array to write data into it next time.

Comment: I disagree: CUDA device memory allocation is not *generally* the main bottleneck of CUDA program performance.

Comment: @harrism: What do you think about it? I think, the main bottlenecks appear at the border from host to device. This is one of them=)

Comment: Careful programmers avoid allocation inside inner loops (or kernels) whenever possible, whether on the host or on the device. Memory transfers (at the border of host and device) and memory bandwidth (device or host) are common bottlenecks, but memory allocation is a much less common bottleneck in real-world code, in my experience.

Comment: @harrism: the comment about memory performance might be directed at device side malloc/new, which isn't particular fast (or wasn't last time I benchmarked it).

Comment: But device-side malloc is also not the GENERAL case in CUDA programming.  marina.k wrote "Generally, CUDA device memory allocation is the main bottleneck of program performance."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the CUDA and all GPGPU stuff bottleneck is transfer from host to device and back.

But in kernels, use always everything known size. 
Kernel must not do malloc... it is very very weird from the concept of the platform.
Even if you have 'for' - loop in CUDA kernel, think 20 times about is your approach optimal, you must be doing realy complex algorithm. Is it really necessary on the  parallel platform ?
You would not believe what problems could come if you don't )))

Use buffered approach. You determine some buffer size, what is more dependent of CUDA requirements( read -> hardware), then of your array. You call a kernel in the loop and upload, process and retrieve data from there. 
Ones, your array of data will be finished and last buffer will be not full. 
You can pass the size of each buffer as single value (pointer to an int for example), what each thread will compare to its thread id, to determine do it if it is possible to get some value or it would be out of bounds. 
Only the last block will have divergence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an useful link: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/

You can do in your kernel function something like this, using shared memory:

```
__global__ void dynamicReverse(int *d, int n)
{
  extern __shared__ int s[];
  .....
}
```

and when you call the kernel function on host, having third parameter the shared memory size, precisely `n*sizeof(int)`:
  `dynamicReverse<<<1,n,n*sizeof(int)>>>(d_d, n);`

Also, it's a best practice to split a huge kernel function, if possible, in more kernel functions, having less code and are easier to execute.